# Google Earth and Windows application

Tags: c++, c, winapi, google-maps

I have a C++ Windows application continually updating lat, long and altitude.
I would like my application to incorporate Google **Earth** to visually "track it".
Any advice or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed the Google Earth plugin into your application as an ActiveX control. The API for the control can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin.html). You need to instantiate your GEPlugin control and from here you can retrieve all the other COM objects. There is no need to register with Google for the development key. This is not supported by Google as it bypasses the official method of development using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Starting point - look at using a web browser as a control/component. For example, Internet Explorer can be used as an ActiveX control. Not easy in plain C++, but supported by MFC - which I'm not very familiar with.

I can't give any more specific pointers than that, unfortunately, except that I tried it once a few years ago (just for fun) and couldn't get it to work. I could get it into a dialog, but when I told it to load a page, it would stay blank.

Still, it *is* possible - look at all the magazine coverdisks that have "their own web browser".

Answer (score 1):

Sep,
Can you provide a few more details on how to do this with the GE Plugin?  I've gotten it working by embedding a browser object in my C# app, but not directly as an ActiveX control.  If I can avoid having to create a web site to host javascript, then I'm all for that.  Thanks!
Bob